# Creating branches using VisualSVN server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am learning SVN and was trying to create a branch on my SVN server, and I found option to create same using command line only.

Is there a way to create a branch using VisualSVN server GUI?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Subversion client for this task. For example, use Subversion command-line client and run `svn copy`, use TortoiseSVN client and run the corresponding copy command in its graphical interface or use any other Subversion client you prefer.

And don't forget to read the documentation:

- [SVNBook | Branching and merging](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/branchmerge/)
- [TortoiseSVN Manual | Branching and tagging](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html)